# Android library project - obfuscation

Tags: android, jar, obfuscation, android-library

I'm preparing Android library for re-distribution and it's code must be obfuscated. I've read something about this topic and I've decided to use Android Library Project. It will be distributed as a jar (automatically created in /bin directory (I'm using eclipse with newest ADT). All the resources (layouts, drawables, etc.) will be distributed in separate package, which developer must add to his project manually (same as manifest permissions and so). So till now everything works - jar added to my clean project does what it should and it sees resources added to my base project. But the problem is when I want to obfuscate this library jar (the one generated automatically in Library project's /bin directory). Since Eclipse supports obfuscation with Proguard only in regular Android projects (when building APK), it doesn't provide obfuscation for Android Library Project (jar isn't obfuscated, even when line "proguard.config=proguard.cfg" is added to project.properties file). I think that the best way to obfuscate such a jar is to use Proguard outside from Eclipse then, but I don't know why I always get "empty output jar" - even when using parameters that I always used in my regular project, before I've decided to extract library from this. Tested with proguard 4.6, 4.7, 4.8 with the same effect. I would be grateful if anyone could show me example proguard.conf that will allow for obfuscation of android library project (e.g. basing on facebook Android Library Project that can be downloaded here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/zipball/master). Every step-by-step instruction will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "automatically created in /bin directory" -- that JAR is not safe for distribution.

Comment: Why not? If you mean it's not obfuscated - I know, it's what I exactly want to do. But not obfuscated it works fine.

Comment: "Why not?" -- because Google said so. There is no support for creating redistributable JARs from Android library projects at this time. That JAR is a side-effect of the build process; it is not something that Google intends on supporting for redistribution.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Google doesn't support illegal activities, either, yet they're still possible with the tools they provide. 

Could you please clarify why that jar is "not safe for distribution"? If a future SDK change makes a similar process impossible, an alternative way of creating the jar may be found, but I see no reason the current method would create a defective or unsafe jar.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Also, what you wrote seems contrary to this: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects ("(...)the new library project feature that generates each library project into its own JAR file"). Granted, it doesn't feature the word "redistributable", but why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @kaay: "why wouldn't it be" -- because Xavier Duchrohet said they weren't when I asked him. And since he's the guy in charge of the tools, he should know. You, of course, are welcome to do whatever you want with whatever files the tools create. However, please do not whine if something does not work.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks. I've tried contacting him, unsuccessfully, so we are still left with no reasons/details. Are you aware of any specific dangers, assuming no resources or user1679590's setup? Would be good to know which cases this lack of safety concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"-dontshrink" will keep all classes. To be more selective, use the various "-keep" options.

Comment: Thanks. "-dontshrink" does the job, but I'll try to adjust "keep" options also.

Comment: I am getting, "can't find super
class or interface android.app.Fragment","can't find superclass
 or interface android.app.ActionBar$TabListener","can't find referenced class a
ndroid.app.ActionBar$Tab" like so many warnings.I am using ActionBar with fragments in Android version 3.0 and above. Can you please give me the  suggesstion how to obfuscate using Proguard?